# Other website in div (with shift)

Tags: html

I am preparing now custom home page to my browser. I would like to few divs displays my favorite websites. However, since I do not have lots of space, I would like to display only the small fragments, with major sections. Is there a way to put excerpts with HTML? I mean the display, for example, to google put in a frame displaying only google-doodle and bar display (shift of tens of pixels to the right and down). I using this code, but i can't add right and down shift :

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="width: 90%; height: 300px"></iframe>
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Warning :  Google website it's only examples. I need to put in a few divs completely different pages. I am not concerned here with a static screenshot, but about full-working piece of the pages.

I make a graphic depicting what I mean :
[image: Additional graphic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle with - what I believe is - what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/3g47mjtk/

Set the width and height of iframe to the webpage size and then clip it down to the size you want. You can remove `scrolling="no"` in the iframe tag if you'd like.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <iframe width="600" height="660" src="http://www.wikipedia.org" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Set #outerdiv to size of #innerdiv. Blue background is so you can see what has happened to the iframe</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#outerdiv {
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#innerdiv {
    position: absolute;
    top:-160px;
    left:-200px;
    clip:rect(160px 400px 360px 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is your browser, then I believe there's functionality to get screenshots/snapshots of your favorite websites built into its extensions business (which is really just lots of javascript and stuffs).    Might want to look into creating an extension for Chrome that becomes your default/new-tab business (there are already a bunch out there in the Chrome Store).

Comment: But google it's only examples. I need to put in a few divs completely different pages. I am not concerned here with a static screenshot, but about full-working piece of the pages.